# C Matrix Multiplication Using Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

Hey everyone so I am making a matrix multiplier using pointers and I have hit a wall. I have made it thus far and have now hit a roadblock.

**My issue:** My resulting matrix is returning values too large when producing a matrix of **size 3x3 or greater** (2x2 and 1x1 return correct values).

Here is **EDITED code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

    void main() {
        int i, j, k, m, n, p, q, m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;
        double **m1, **m2, **mr;
        printf("Enter number of rows and columns of 1st matrix:");
        scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
        printf("Enter number of rows and columns of 2nd matrix:");
        scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);

        if(n!=p) printf("Not possible");
        else {
        m1 = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m1_rows);
        for(int i=0; i < m1_rows; i++) m1[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m1_cols);

        m2 = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m2_rows);
        for(int i=0; i < m2_rows; i++) m2[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m2_cols);

        mr = malloc(sizeof(double *) * mr_rows);
        for(int i=0; i < mr_rows; i++) mr[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * mr_cols);

        printf("Enter 1st matrix values:");
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<m1_cols;j++) {
                scanf("%d",(&m1[i][j]));
            }
        }

        printf("Enter 2nd matrix values:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m2_rows;i++) for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++) scanf("%d",(*(m2+i)+j));

        printf("First matrix is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<m1_cols;j++) printf("%d\t",*(*(m1+i)+j)); }

        printf("\nSecond matrix is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m2_rows;i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++) printf("%d\t",*(*(m2+i)+j)); }

        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++) {
                *(*(mr+i)+j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You might like to (re-)read about how to implement multi-dimensional arrays in general and on how to (type-safe) handle pointers in particular.

Comment: @Blue00d - I cannot see the declarations for the integers m, n, p, q.
May be that's an issue.

Comment: Hint: You want to store `double`s, but you allocate multiples of the size of a pointer to `double`: `malloc(sizeof(double*) * ...` this is asking for trouble.

Comment: It would really help if you checked the values of ` m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;` while the program was running...

Comment: It would really help if you checked the values of `m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;` while the program was running...

Comment: It would really help if you checked the values of `m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;` while the program was running...

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that you try to allocate a two-dimensional data structure using only a single dimension, but you still use a two-dimensional type (pointer to pointer). How wrong it is you ill see if you change the code to use array-indexing syntax instead, for example

```
*(m1+i)+j
```

would be

```
&m1[i][j]
```

Using array-indexing syntax you should see that you don't actually allocate the second dimension. You have space allocated for it, but it simply doesn't work like that, because the memory layout of a two-dimensional array is not the same as the layout of a two-dimensional array using pointers to pointers.

---

To further explain the difference between an array of arrays (where all data is in a contiguous block) and a pointer-to-pointer, see the following figures:

For example the declaration

```
double a[2][2];
```

the memory is laid out as

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

But if you use e.g. a pointer to pointer:

```
double **a;
```

then a after proper allocation it looks like this

```
+------+------+-----+
| a[0] | a[1] | ... |
+------+------+-----+
  |      |
  |      V
  |      +---------+---------+-----+
  |      | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | ... |
  |      +---------+---------+-----+
  V
  +---------+---------+-----+
  | a[0][0] | a[0][1] | ... |
  +---------+---------+-----+
```

Hopefully you should now understand why, in your case, doing `m1[x]` (for any `x`) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as it's a pointer which is uninitialized.

---

A simple solution to this problem? Simply do two allocations: One for the "rows" and one for the "columns".

Like

```
m1 = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m1_rows);
for (int i = 0; i < m1_rows; ++i)
    m1[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m1_columns);
```

Comment: I took your advice and changed *(m1+i)+j to &m1[i][j] but now it crashes as soon as it tries to scan in for m1 (line 26). What am I missing?

Comment: It would really help if you checked the values of `m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;` while the program was running...

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

- To print a `double` use `%f`. `%d` is for `int`.
- To scan in a `double` use `%lf`. `%d` is for `int`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Variables `m1_rows`, `m1_cols`, `m2_rows`, `m2_cols`, `mr_rows` and `mr_cols` are not initialized, however you are using it during memory allocation.

2) Use `%f` or `%lf` for double data types. `%d` is use for int.

3) You are not performing any matrix multiplication, so need to perform matrix multiplication and also print the result.

4) After allocating memory for pointer don't forget to free those pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int i, j, k, m, n, p, q, m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows, mr_cols;
    double **m1, **m2, **mr;
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of 1st matrix:");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of 2nd matrix:");
    scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);
    // m1_rows, m1_cols, m2_rows, m2_cols, mr_rows and mr_cols are not initialized, however you are using it during memory allocation
    m1_rows = m;
    m1_cols = n;
    m2_rows = p;
    m2_cols = q;
    mr_rows = m;
    mr_cols = q;

    if(n!=p) printf("Not possible");
    else 
    {
        m1 = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m1_rows);
        for(i=0; i < m1_rows; i++) m1[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m1_cols);

        m2 = malloc(sizeof(double *) * m2_rows);
        for(i=0; i < m2_rows; i++) m2[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m2_cols);

        mr = malloc(sizeof(double *) * mr_rows);
        for(i=0; i < mr_rows; i++) mr[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * mr_cols);

        printf("Enter 1st matrix values:");
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) 
        {
            for(j=0;j<m1_cols;j++) 
            {
                scanf("%lf",&m1[i][j]);
            }
        }

        printf("Enter 2nd matrix values:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m2_rows;i++) 
        {
            for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++)
            {
                scanf("%lf",&m2[i][j]);
            }
        }

        printf("First matrix is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) 
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<m1_cols;j++)
            {
                printf("%.2lf\t",*(*(m1+i)+j)); 
            }
        }

        printf("\nSecond matrix is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m2_rows;i++) 
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++)
            {
                printf("%.2lf\t",*(*(m2+i)+j)); 
            }
        }
        //Matrix multiplication
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++) 
        {
            for(j=0;j<m2_cols;j++) 
            {
                mr[i][j] = 0;
                for(k=0;k<m1_cols;k++)
                {
                    mr[i][j] = mr[i][j]+m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        //Print the result
        printf("\nResult matrix is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<mr_rows;i++) 
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<mr_cols;j++)
            {
                printf("%.2lf\t",mr[i][j]); 
            }
        }
        //Free the allocated memory
        for(i=0;i<m1_rows;i++)
        {
            free(m1[i]);
        }
        free(m1);
        for(i=0;i<m2_rows;i++)
        {
            free(m2[i]);
        }
        free(m2);
        for(i=0;i<mr_rows;i++)
        {
            free(mr[i]);
        }
        free(mr);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick attempt at showing a way to implement your logic. One issue, as shown in the comment, was the myriad of unitialized variables in your code. When possible, don't duplicate variables under different names -- that just opens up additional possible errors. Let me know if you have questions. (I have retained your pointer equivalences: `m1[i][j] = *(*(m1+i)+j)` just to show they are interchangeable ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int c, i = 0, j = 0, m = 0, n = 0, p = 0, q = 0;
    double **m1, **m2, **mr;

    printf ("Enter number of rows and columns of 1st matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d %d", &m, &n);
    do { c = getchar (); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);   /* flush input buffer */

    printf ("Enter number of rows and columns of 2nd matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d %d", &p, &q);
    do { c = getchar (); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);   /* flush input buffer */

    if (n != p)
        printf ("Not possible\n");
    else {
        m1 = malloc (sizeof (double *) * m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            m1[i] = calloc (n, sizeof (double));    /* use calloc to 0 elements */

        m2 = malloc (sizeof (double *) * p);
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            m2[i] = calloc (q, sizeof (double));    /* use calloc to 0 elements */

        mr = malloc (sizeof (double *) * m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            mr[i] = calloc (q, sizeof (double));    /* use calloc to 0 elements */

        printf ("Enter 1st matrix values:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf ("  m1[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
                scanf ("%lf", &m1[i][j]);
                do { c = getchar (); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);   /* flush input buffer */
            }
        }

        printf ("Enter 2nd matrix values:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < q; j++) {
                printf ("  m1[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
                scanf ("%lf", &(*(*(m2 + i))));
                do { c = getchar (); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);   /* flush input buffer */
            }

        printf ("\nFirst matrix is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            printf ("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                printf ("%lf\t", *(*(m1 + i) + j));
        }

        printf ("\n\nSecond matrix is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            printf ("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < q; j++)
                printf ("%lf\t", *(*(m2 + i) + j));
        }

        printf ("\n");

        /* THIS FREES NOTHING - allocate with calloc or use memset to 0 */
//         for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
//             for(j=0;j<q;j++) {
//                 *(*(mr+i)+j) = 0;
//             }
//         }


        printf ("\nFree First matrix\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (*(m1 + i))
                free (*(m1 + i));
        }
        if (m1)
            free (m1);

        printf ("Free Second matrix\n");
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            if (*(m2 + i))
                free (*(m2 + i));
        }
        if (m2)
            free (m2);

        printf ("Free Result matrix\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (*(mr + i))
                free (*(mr + i));
        }
        if (mr)
            free (mr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**build:**

**Note: always build with at least `-Wall -Wextra` which will identify problems in your code.**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-long-long -std=c99 -o bin/badmtrx badmtrx.c
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/badmtrx
Enter number of rows and columns of 1st matrix: 1 3
Enter number of rows and columns of 2nd matrix: 3 1
Enter 1st matrix values:
    m1[0][0]: 1
    m1[0][1]: 2
    m1[0][2]: 3
Enter 2nd matrix values:
    m1[0][0]: 4
    m1[1][0]: 5
    m1[2][0]: 6

First matrix is:

1.000000        2.000000        3.000000

Second matrix is:

4.000000
5.000000
6.000000

Free First matrix
Free Second matrix
Free Result matrix
```

**valgrind heap summary:**

```
==10711== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10711==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10711==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 96 bytes allocated
==10711==
==10711== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10711==
==10711== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
--10711--
--10711-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==10711==
==10711== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```